# Use eq filter to half of the video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use an eq filler to increase the saturation of half of the video, that is, half of the screen will be changed and the other half will remain unchanged.

Example:
[eq filter on half of the video screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMcn2.jpg)

I was able to achieve this by using the crop and hstack filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0,eq=saturation=0.4[left];\
    [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0,eq=saturation=3[right];\
    [left][right]hstack[out]" \
    -map "[out]" -c:v libx264 -threads 1 -t 5 -n "Intro\output.mp4"
```

**However, is there a faster way to apply this filter to half of the video?**